# How can I get a chart only with legends using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have various highcharts containers/charts without legend each in a grid. Now I want to create a highcharts but only want to show the legends to represent the previous data in the previous charts.

I've try to create a chart using `spacing: [0,0,0,0]` and a lot of series without data `{ data: [] }, { data: [] }` but I can't get the legend in the middle of the container [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbkunst/dq4tr387/)

[image]

As you see, there's a space I can't remove yet. I trid use `padding` in the `legend` option without success

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite what you want but this may work close enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000546/highchart-legend-into-another-element-div

Comment: Is another alternative I did'nt think it. Thanks for point this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use legend.verticalAlign, legend.maxHeight and legend.padding parameters to position your legend in the right place:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.verticalAlign
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.maxHeight
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.padding

```
legend: {
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  maxHeight: 200
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/dq4tr387/2/

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz. Finally, why `-40`?

Comment: Good question :) it was just an example - it all depends on your charts height. Right now I think that better solution will be to use verticalAlign: http://jsfiddle.net/dq4tr387/2/